# Sortable not working in modal but works on the page launching the modal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui-sortable

I am currently trying to make a list available to be re-ordered using drag and drop in a modal. My modal is below...

```
<div class="modal fade" id="settingsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg"> 
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Settings</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">

            <ul id="sortable">

                <li data-id="1" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Test 1</li>
                <li data-id="2" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Test 2</li>
                <li data-id="3" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Test 3</li>

            </ul>

        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">

          <button id="save-reorder" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

The javascript looks like this...

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
```

When I use this code on the page that launches the modal, it works just fine. I am not sure why this is not working in the modal as well. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" >

    <script src="jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



</head>

    <div class="modal fade" id="settingsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true"> 
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg"> 
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Settings</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">

            <ul id="sortable">

                <li data-id="1" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Test 1</li>
                <li data-id="2" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Test 2</li>
                <li data-id="3" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Test 3</li>

            </ul>

        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">

          <button id="save-reorder" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 <a href="javascript://" id="target" >Open Modal</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

     $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();


});
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
   $("#settingsModal").modal('show');
});

</script>
```